# Get original request info after a forward in Symfony 2

Tags: symfony

I have created a custom Error 403 page using the `access_denied_url` parameter in `security.yml`: when showing the new page I want to tell people that the problem happened when trying to access page xxxxx.

`$request->headers->get('referer')` is empty.

```
/**
 * @Route("/forbidden", name="error_403")
 * @Template()
 */
public function error403Action(Request $request)
{
    return array('referer' => $request->headers->get('referer'));
}
```

How can I get information about the original Request (the one that resulted in this forward)?

Comment: Just accept your answer instead of changing the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It got solved calling `{{ app.request.server.get('PHP_SELF') }}` directly in the Twig template.